# How to pre-cache NSImage for displaying inside NSImageView

Tags: macos, cocoa, caching, nsimage, nsimageview

I have a rather large image, which I display inside `NSImageView`. Once I do it the first time, every next usage of said image is very fast. Either when re-using the `NSImageView` it was assigned to or assigning it to a new `NSImageView`. This is apparently due to the fact that `NSImage` keeps cache of the representation it used for displaying said image the first time. The problem is with displaying it the first time though. Even on a fast hardware there is an unacceptably long delay before the image eventually appears. What I am looking for is a way to pre-cache the image representation before I display it the first time. Any suggestions?

FWIW, I use Obj-C for OS X/macOS but I believe it shouldn't make any difference and Swift techniques should be applicable too.

Comment: The `valid` property may help: *... this method loads the data and expands it as needed...*.

Comment: @GerdK - I use isValid() (the getter for the property in question) before displaying the image so this seems not to help. I also use `initWithContentsOfFile` rather than `initByReferencingFile` so that it's not lazy-loaded.